# Trying to register on the Code Review site gives error

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, stack-exchange-openid, sign-up

I'm trying to register on Code Review.  One of my [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731573/how-would-you-improve-this-scala-basic-xml-template) was closed and I was recommended to post it there.

However, when I clicked on the link I received in my email to complete the registration, I got a message saying:

> It appears that the security of this request has been tampered with.

Now, after a few attempts, I landed on "*Not found*" page.

After second try when using my existing stackoverflow account gives:

> An error occurred on the server This event has been recorded. If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it.

I have one: blackbox. I was logged on Stakoverflow when I tried to register on code review. I thought they were separate sites, so I tried to register a new account. Hope that helps.

What should I do?

Comment: Now trying to use my existing stackoverflow account gives : An error occurred on the server
This event has been recorded.

If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it.

Comment: I see no sign that you even have an SO account, so you apparently confused the server badly

Comment: I have one : blackbox. I was logged on Stakoverflow when I tried to register on code review. I thought they were separate sites, so I tried to regiter a new account. Hope that helps...

Comment: The account used to ask the question on Stack Overflow you are referring, and that has been closed, is [snoir](http://stackoverflow.com/users/802793/snoir). You don't have an account that uses "blackbox" as username, on Stack Overflow. Every SE site use a different account; the accounts are linked if you use the same OpenID account on different SE sites.